# Sum of digits of N to the power P

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, integer-arithmetic

My C++ code is supposed to take a number and an exponent as integer inputs, calculate the 'number' to the power of THAT 'exponent' and sum the digits of the result and output it. It works well for small exponent values like 10 or 20, but gives wrong answers for large values like ~ >500. I have limited my 'number' inputs to <5 for wease of computability. I cannot figure out what is wrong with my logic.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <cmath>


int main(){

  int number, exponent;
  cin >> number >> exponent;
  double product = 1;

  int sum = 0;

  // Write your code here
  for (int i = 0; i < exponent; i++){ 
    product = product * number;
  }
  cout << "THE MAIN PRODUCT IS: " << product << "\n\n";

  while (product > 1){
    sum = sum + fmod(product, 10.0);  // kEEP ADDING THE DIGITS TO THE SUM
    cout << "sum is " << sum << endl;
    product = product / 10.000;
    cout << "product is " << product << endl;
  }

  cout << endl;
  cout << sum << endl;
}
```

Comment: just an FYI 2^1000 is a large number

Comment: Do you understand what *integer overflow* is?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel no , could you explain it to me?

Comment: @mightyWOZ, yes and my code gives incorrect output for this order of numbers

Comment: I think the italicized keyword "integer overflow" was given to you as search tearm so that you can do your own investigation. This is basic stuff.

Comment: (You use double-precision floating-point numbers, which can represent a larger range of numbers, but they cannot represent all numbers in the range. You will probably not get the correct digit sum.)

Comment: `what is wrong with my logic.`-> nothing.. it is correct. | `limited my 'number' inputs to <5` -> good, but not enough... 'int' can only handle values at these limits : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_data_types.htm | u need to limit the user input for both number n exponent.. right?

Comment: You actually could solve that problem without a computer (with pencil and paper). Observe first that 1 + 2 + 3 .... + 500 is the same as 500 + 499 + ... + 2 + 1. Sum them piece by piece (1 + 500) + (2 + 499) + .... + (1 + 500). Etc. With sum of squares, remember that `(x+y)*(x+y)` is `x*x` + `y*y` + `2*x*y`, etc.

Comment: since u just need to know how many digit.. i think this [log equation](https://www.had2know.com/academics/compute-number-digits-exponents-calculator.html) should do. is this what u r looking for?

Comment: @p._phidot_ I have to calculate (number ^ exponent) eg. is 2^300 or 7 ^500, and then add up all the digits of the resulting large number

Comment: so 2^7 will result in.. ?

Comment: @p._phidot_ it would be 128, so output of my code is 1 + 2 + 8 = 11 (final output)

Comment: so (refer link in my 1st comment) ur code fails if in went beyond int limit.

Comment: @p._phidot_ On it! Thanks a lot

Comment: but if u have matlab/mathematica.. it is very possible to do. [example](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+the+digits+for+2%5E7). | To break that limit.. and use the same method.. but apply "arbitrary precision arithmetic" library, like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Multiple_Precision_Arithmetic_Library

Answer (score 2):

The issue with a large exponent is the length of the final answer or the number of digits in the final answer.

In C++, the largest integer that can be represented is 18-19 digits.

If the number exceeds beyond a limit, it will cause an integer overflow.

So, the best way to tackle this problem is to make use of strings or integer arrays.

Have a look at the following implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

// Maximum number of digits in
// output
#define MAX 100000


int multiply(int x, int res[], int res_size) {

    // Initialize carry
    int carry = 0;

    // One by one multiply n with
    // individual digits of res[]
    for (int i = 0; i < res_size; i++) {
        int prod = res[i] * x + carry;

        // Store last digit of
        // 'prod' in res[]
        res[i] = prod % 10;

        // Put rest in carry
        carry = prod / 10;
}

    // Put carry in res and
    // increase result size
    while (carry) {
        res[res_size] = carry % 10;
        carry = carry / 10;
        res_size++;
    }

    return res_size;
}

// This function finds
// power of a number x
long long power(int x, int n)
{

    //printing value "1" for power = 0
    if(n == 0 ){
        return 1;
    }


    int res[MAX];
    int res_size = 0;
    int temp = x;

    // Initialize result
    // Representing base in reverse form
    while (temp != 0) {
        res[res_size++] = temp % 10;
        temp = temp / 10;
    }

    // Multiply x n times
    // (x^n = x*x*x....n times)
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
        res_size = multiply(x, res, res_size);


    long long final_answer = 0;
    
    //Finally taking sum of all the digits in the answer.
    for(int i=0;i<res_size; i++){
        
        final_answer += res[i];    
    }    
    
    return final_answer;
}


int main() {
    int exponent = 8;
    int base = 34;
    std::cout<<power(base, exponent);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
76
```